# Ein digitales Foto "teilen" (vom Englischen to share)

Tags: english-to-german

Meistens wird das Englische "to share" mit dem Verb "teilen" plump in das Deutsche übersetzt.
Im Englischen wird das Verb "**to share**" dafür verwendet wenn man zum Beispiel ein digitales Foto jemand anderem zugänglich machen möchte.

In diesem Fall halbiere ich das Foto aber nicht. Wenn ich ein Brot teile dann halbiere ich es und teile es so mit jemandem. Ein analoges Foto teile ich ja auch nicht wenn ich es jemandem zeige.

Im Internet werden Fotos aber anders mit jemandem "geteilt".

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer präzisen Übersetzung des Englischen "to share" im Zusammenhang mit **digitalen Kopien**.

Comment: ein Foto weiterverbreiten, an andere senden, einem größeren Kreis zugänglich machen, öffentlich machen, publik machen.

Comment: Es ist schade, dass _mitteilen_ schon "besetzt" ist. Auf Italienisch ist _condividere_ (_con=mit_, _divìdere=teilen_) die genaue Übersetzung von _to share_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Häufig wird

> freigeben

verwendet, wenn digitale Inhalte (Dokumente, Bilder etc.) für andere explizit zugänglich gemacht werden.

In Windows z. B. wurde der Begriff "(network) share" mit "(Netzwerk-)Freigabe" übersetzt.

Umgangssprachlich werden auch häufig die englischen Begriffe verwendet:

> "Hast du die Fotos von der Party echt geshared?!?"
>   "Ja, hab sie in meinen Public-Folder von Dropbox gelegt."
>   "Krass."

Comment: @Takkat Beim Facebooken wurde ich angechattet. Ein Typ, der mich auf Twitter gefriended hat, hat den Link beim Youtuben entdeckt. ;-)

Comment: Hast du es im SPS eingecheckt? Nein ich will es doch auch wiederfinden. Ich habs als Frage bei SO bereitgestellt. OK passt nicht ganz zu Fotos.

Comment: Vermutlich gibt es da bald ein Wort, das von www.tumblr.com abgeleitet ist.

Comment: Was ist nun "korrekter", _geshared_ oder _gesharet_?

Answer (score 8):

> Geteiltes Leid ist halbes Leid, geteilte Freude ist doppelte Freude

Dieses Sprichwort deutet recht gut die entgegengesetzten Bedeutungen des Verbs *teilen* an. Wenn man eine Emotion, oder allgemeiner eine Information, mit jemandem teilt, dann behält man ja die Information selber auch noch, man vergrößert also den Wirkbereich der Information.

Somit ist *teilen* durchaus eine passende und elegante Übersetzung für *to share*.

*Teilen* kann natürlich auch eine physikalische Teilung bedeuten - da es aber explizit um digitale Fotografien geht, ist die Bedeutung hier eindeutig.

Der Knackpunkt ist wahrscheinlich, dass das *Teilen* von Informationen im Deutschen immer einer gewissen Konstruktion bedarf:

> Ich **teile** das Bild **mit** Dir.

während im Englischen die Information ganz abstrakt "geshared" werden kann, ohne expliziten Empfänger:

> I share the photo.

was, ins Deutsche rückübersetzt:

> Ich teile das Foto.

natürlich nicht wie beabsichtigt funktioniert.

Wenn also *Teilen* als 1-Wort-Übersetzung nicht funktioniert, wäre

> Mitteilen

noch eine Möglichkeit. Klingt aber schon recht formell.

Eine weitere Möglichkeit, *to share* in einem Wort zu übersetzen, ist etwas freier:

> Weitersagen

Das ist im Gegensatz zu "verfügbar machen" immerhin kein Beamtendeutsch und ein Stück lässiger als *mitteilen*.

Comment: `Mitteilen` isn't a good word here. It means "to tell someone something" or "to communicate something to someone". It doesn't have any meaning like "to share". Also it's not the same word as in "Ich teile das Bild mit dir" where `mit` is a proposition and not the split off prefix of "mitteilen". `Weitersagen` can have a meaning of "share", but it's used for passing on verbal information and not physical things. ("Sag Peter, dass wir uns morgen treffen" - "Ich werde es weitersagen"; "Tell Peter, that we will meet tomorrow." - "I will pass it on.")

Comment: RoToRa wrote:
"Mitteilen isn't a good word here. It means "to tell someone something" or.... It doesn't have any meaning like "to share". Hier bist du aber gewaltig auf de Holzweg! Hier beschreibt eine Dame aus den USA ein Telefongespräch mit ihrem Arzt:
"I shared with him that I’d had surgeries before and never went through this unease afterwards..."

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dict.cc/?s=teilen+mit sowie

> eine (Charakter)Eigenschaft teilen

lassen mich eher vermuten, dass im Englischen die Konstruktion mit Partikel auch üblich wäre, sie aber wohl hauptsächlich im **Internet-Englisch** nicht (mehr) gemacht wird. V. a. Nicht-Muttersprachler des Englischen haben ja immer Schwierigkeiten, welche Partikeln mit welchen Verben korrekt benutzt werden, und lassen sie dann evtl. einfach weg, v. a. in Chats. Der *share* Button findet sich ja mittlerweile auch auf jeder Webseite. Das Verb scheint mir also durch die starke Benutzung im Internet um die Partikel kastriert worden zu sein.

Ist vielleicht eher eine spannende Frage für english/linguistics.SE, ob der Gebrauch von Partikeln bei engl. Verben, die im Internet häufig genutzt werden, zurückgeht, weil mehr und mehr Nicht-Muttersprachler hinzukommen, oder eben jede "unnötige" Partikel als redundant gespart wird von den Webdesignern, solange man die Bedeutung versteht.

Da mein Englisch noch nicht hauptsächlich im Internet sozialisiert wurde, benutze ich eigentlich meist *share with*, während die heutigen Kids es wohl eher als ***verbreiten/in Umlauf bringen/vervielfältigen*** benutzen, was strenggenommen mit *teilen* nicht mehr viel gemein hat imho.

Answer (score 1):

Eine der Möglichkeiten das Gewünschte auszudrücken ist *verteilen*.